# Python num2words bug in french translation

Tags: python

I am using the [num2words](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words) library for Python in order to translate numbers into french words.
However I have an encoding issue with the following case :

```
num2words((5.05),lang='fr')
```

output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/num2words/__init__.py", line 50, in num2words
return converter.to_cardinal(number)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/num2words/base.py", line 93, in to_cardinal
return self.to_cardinal_float(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/num2words/base.py", line 127, in to_cardinal_float
out.append(str(self.to_cardinal(curr)))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems to be coming from the "zéro" string. But I do not have the problem when there is no dot:

```
num2words((0),lang='fr')
```

output:

```
u'z\xe9ro'
```

Can you please help ?

Thanks !

Comment: You should probably [raise this issue](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words/issues) on the num2words GitHub. I can't tell (because they don't specify) if it's meant to support Python 2, but this is buggy Python 2 support. If possible, upgrading to Python 3 would solve your problem here.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist : ok thanks for your answer. I will try with Python 3 and raise the issue.

Comment: As of today, the package still has other bugs, e.g. French ordinals: it incorrectly returns "quatre-vingtsième" and "deux centsième" for n=80 resp. 200, lang="fr" and to="ordinal".